# How do I stop my index.php being run twice for every user

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We've got a webapp where the initial html is served up using apache and php.

I recently noticed that index.php was being run twice for every request. This seems to be caused / effected by the rewrite rules in our .htaccess -

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.|hotels\.)ourdomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.|hotels\.)ourdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://ourdomain.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^hotels/([^/]+)/?\??(.*)$ ?d=$1&$2 [QSA]
```

The final rule is moving a parameter from the url path to the query string. i.e.

```
http://ourdomain.com/hotels/vegas?someParam=1
```

becomes

```
http://ourdomain.com?d=vegas&someParam=1
```

If I go directly to the query string version then index.php is only run once. However if use a url that will be redirected, then index.php is run twice (I'm checking by adding `error_log('end of index.php')` to the file).

So for example going to `http://ourdomain.com/hotels/paris` hits the file twice where as `http://ourdomain.com?d=paris` only hits it once.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948063/rewriterule-causes-page-to-reload-twice) and had a look at the [blog mentioned](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/16/empty-string-urls-in-html-a-followup/), and I can't find any empty string url's (I've tried using yslow for this process).

Can anybody tell me why this is happening? or how I fix it?

**EDIT**

It looks like it's a javascript error I'm getting http requests like `"GET /hotels/undefined HTTP/1.1"` in the access log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try last rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^hotels/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?d=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Or catch the erroneous requests with

```
RewriteRule ^hotels/((?!undefined)[^/]+)/?$ index.php?d=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm afraid index.php now runs 5 times instead of just 2.

Comment: :) then I think your test is not correct. Enable rewrite log and then check how many times `index.php` is invoked

Comment: Sorry, you're right. still twice. (for some reason our session logger is logging multiple sessions now - which is actually the original bug I was trying fix). Thanks for you time anyway.

Comment: Yes `GET /hotels/undefined HTTP/1.1` will cause your `index.php` to be invoked again. You can avoid it by using: `RewriteRule ^hotels/((?!undefined)[^/]+)/?$ index.php?d=$1 [NC,QSA,L]`

Comment: Thanks @anubhava - that makes sense. It's pretty hacky though. I guess if I can't find the js responsible, I might have to try it.

Comment: Wow - not easy! think something's writing undefined to a img src attribute (accept image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5 in the http request), but what's doing it is very difficult to identify. Actually went with RewriteRule ^hotels/undefined - [L,R=404] in the end.